# iOS: How to temporarily persist data without database?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a small game where users answer questions. The overall flow will go like this:

1. Select a difficulty level by clicking a button (push segue)
2. Player 1 enters name, press "Next" (push segue)
3. Answer question
4. Answer question
5. Finish.
6. Player 2 enters name, press "Next" (push segue)
7. Answer question
8. Answer question
9. Finish.
10. Look at everyone's answers
11. Get sent back to #1

My problem is I don't really need to store user info (name, answers, etc) in a database since that data is useless after the round is over. However, I need it to persist enough so that I can access that data across the view controllers before the round is over.

For the difficulty level I'm using a custom property on AppDelegate to persist the setting:

AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *difficultyLevel;

@end
```

DifficultyViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)setDifficultyLevel:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSString *difficulty = [[button titleLabel] text];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.difficultyLevel = difficulty;
}
```

PlayerProfileViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"Edmund: %@", appDelegate.difficultyLevel);
}
```

However, this doesn't feel very scalable since I am going to have many other properties and I don't feel like that's what AppDelegate is meant to be used for.

Is there a common way to persist data for this sort of thing?

Comment: Why you don't create a singleton class "SharedData" and store there all your data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a kind of game manager. A manager is commonly used as a singleton that means you will have only one instance of this class. It could be something like:

-header file:

```
@interface GameManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *difficultyLevel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *player1Name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *player2Name;
@end
```

-source file:

```
@implementation GameManager

@synthesize difficultyLevel, player1Name, player2Name;

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static GameManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // add what you need here
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And so you will update your code like that:

```
- (IBAction)setDifficultyLevel:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSString *difficulty = [[button titleLabel] text];
    GameManager *gameManager = [GameManager sharedInstance];
    gameManager.difficultyLevel = difficulty;
}
```

You can also have a weak property on your manager in each view controller if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks! what exactly does the dispatch stuff do? is that coming from C? it doesn't look like objective c

Comment: This is to avoid several threads creating an instance of your singleton at the "same" time. More info here: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-06-06-secrets-of-dispatch_once.html